# ECS Fargate stops pulling image from ECR

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

ECS task are unable to start with stoppedCode as below:

```
CannotPullContainerError: pull image manifest has been retried 5 time(s): failed to resolve ref 709686272029.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/leo-imap-connection-manager:latest: failed to do request: Head "https://709686272029.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v2/leo-imap-connection-manager/manifests/latest": dial tcp 52.35.2.78:443: i/o timeout
Stopped: September 18, 2023 at 13:50 (UTC-4:00)
```

The network configurations are perfect as the error gets fixed automatically after couple of retries!! There have been no changes done on network and routing!!!

[image]

Comment: If it is not due to the ongoing issues at AWS, then it could be that your network configuration is **not** perfect. For example each deployment attempt will use a random subnet from the subnets you have configured for your ECS task. If some, but not all, of those subnets is not configured correctly with access to ECR, then this type of intermittent issue could occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS is experiencing significant multi-service issues in us-west-2 and us-east-1 right now.

https://health.aws.amazon.com/health/status

[image]